# Updated value of Apex Variable not reflecting in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have declared a boolean variable in apex

```
public Boolean StandardOnload{get;set;}
```

I have a VF page  for this controller and in the vf page there is a outputPanel which is rendered on the basis of the Boolean in apex

```
<apex:outputPanel id="gr1" rendered="{!!StandardOnload}">
```

On the first load it is working fine, but inside my VF i have a dropdown and on the basis of that I am calling an action to update the value of this boolean

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!testMethod}" reRender="op1,pb1,gr1,gr2,gr22" status="spinnerStatus" oncomplete="showSave();" />
```

this is the testMethod

```
public void testMethod()
    {
        
        StandardOnload = true;
        
    }
```

But the value of Boolean is not updated in the context of vf.

Can someone please tell if i am missing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `rerender` and `render` together, once the element is removed from the DOM, it can't be rendered again until there's a full page load. This is a limitation of how Visualforce performs its partial render logic. Make sure the target doesn't disappear.

In other words, you can do this:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="gr1">
  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!StandardOnload}">
```

Or just placing the ID somewhere up the component hierarchy, such that the conditionally rendered component is a child of the ID.